# Algorithms for equivalence of 2 way finite automata (2DFA)

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory

I'm interested in the computational complexity of deciding equivalence of 2DFAs.

It is known that converting 2DFA to DFA can incur a blow up in states. However I'm not sure whether this automatically tells us something about the complexity of 2DFA equivalence.

Which leads to my question: Is there a hardness result for 2DFA equivalence like the PSPACE-completeness of language equivalence of NFAs and regular expressions. Conversely, I am interested in literature I might have missed that algorithmically solves the equivalence problem directly on 2DFA, without translating to DFAs first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer to this question:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-emptiness-problem-for-2-way-dfas

The complexity of emptiness for 2-WAY DFAs is already PSPACE complete, so equivalence is also PSPACE-hard (and membership in PSPACE is easy by the single-exponential translation to DFA).

Comment: Thanks! This is the reference I needed.